# What is the limit of human memory?

Tags: memory

I am currently a high school student and have grown curious at what the limitation of memory storage in the brain might be in humans.

**Information is coded genetically and stored in the brain, but is there a limit to how much information a person can retain without forgetting?**

In high school I have taken a broad courses in biology, chemistry, physics, calculus and more. I wonder if my desire to learn and keep moving forward will be hindered mentally by the intrinsic aspects of memory (if they do exist)?

Comment: You may want to see this question which is similar to yours (but I think not exactly a duplicate) - this question talks about actual "memory" in terms of connections of neurons in the central nervous system... http://biology.stackexchange.com/q/19614/16299

Comment: @VanceLAlbaugh Yes I saw it, but there are some memories which can't be exactly recovered after some time.

Comment: (1) `Information is coded genetically and stored in the brain` this sentence sounds really weird and suggest misunderstanding of what genetics is. (2) You might want to study a bit further neuroscience with an online course to see how much you like it. A short introduction can be found on Khan Academy [here](https://www.khanacademy.org/science/biology/human-biology) under `The neuron and nervous system`

Comment: @Remi.b: I think it's referring to new studies that are showing that memories are encoded into the chromosomes present in brain cells. Which makes a lot of sense, since why create a whole new replicative storage system when you already have one? Basically, the genetic material appears to be 'hijacked' and used for local storage instead of reproductive communication, since brain cells won't participate in reproductive communication in any case. It's not 'genetic memory' in the Goa'uld sense, but 'genetic memory' in the 'DNA data storage' sense.

Comment: Wow, I never heard of such thing before. Are you aware of a nice and simple source of information on the subject? Otherwise, I will try to ask for a layman explanation on a different post I guess. Can I eventually cite your comment then? Is there a specific term for this concept?

Comment: @Remi.b @-checking is your friend; I almost missed your reply. Searching for a source now.

Comment: @Remi.b: I think this covers it: http://www.cell.com/cell/abstract/S0092-8674(15)00622-4

Comment: Related: http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/38/is-there-a-practical-limit-to-the-amount-of-knowledge-a-human-can-learn, http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/9732/evidence-of-virtually-limitless-long-term-memory, http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/10705/can-memorising-a-new-thing-erase-existing-memories

Answer (score -3, accepted):

http://www.scientificamerican.com/article/what-is-the-memory-capacity/

https://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-physical-limit-to-human-memory-If-yes-can-it-or-has-it-been-measured

It's said that you store everything or nearly everything you experience in your subconscious mind.

Comment: Your first reference does not talk about the subconscious, in fact, it even contradicts what you are saying: _"Second, certain memories involve more details and thus take up more space; other memories are forgotten and thus free up space. "_

Comment: Neither does the second .... where do you conclude from that it is _"said that you store everything or nearly everything you experience in your subconscious mind"_? From reading your references I do not come to that same conclusion.